# Submitting form via AJAX and getting response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

In my rails app, I need to submit a form via ajax so that the form submit happens behind the scenes and doesn't require a full page reload.

I did form_remote_tag, but I can't figure out how to get a response from it make sure it was successful. Is there a way to, or do people just trust it's always successful (eek!)?

Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you're responding to the AJAX request - probably from a the `create` or `update` action of one of your controllers, you should respond with some javascript or JSON.

If you create an `.rjs` file to respond, it will get executed when the page responds. If everything went well, you can redirect or update the page. If something failed, replace the form with a partial which will display the errors. Read about rjs here: http://www.codyfauser.com/2005/11/20/rails-rjs-templates

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to respond with json now but it causes the browser to throw up a 'save' dialog. I guess it's not expecting json -- if I only knew why.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind a callback to your form_remote_tag that would process your response.

It works fine for me.
Hope will help you out.

Here my code :

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => some_path, :method=>'post',:complete =>'your_callback_method();' do %>
```